# How to use Log Parser Plugin in a Jenkins Workflow script

Tags: jenkins, logparser, jenkins-workflow

The Log Parser Plugin is now [compatible with Workflow](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27208) but how do I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is to use *Snippet Generator* to get an example step statement using it.

Comment: Sure, did not think about it the Snippet Generator... Thanks!

Comment: It's under "step:General Build Step" / "Console output"

Comment: Thank you @PhilippeCarriere, I don't know how I was supposed to know that on my own, very helpful hint. The plugin's documentation could definitely be better.

Answer (score 4):

Snippet Generator is a good idea; however, it is not generating the complete line to make it work. It is necessary to add at the end of the code line "*, projectRulePath: ''*".

Final line will be in the way, for example:

```
logParser failBuildOnError: true, parsingRulePath: '/myRulesPath', showGraphs:true, unstableOnWarning: true, useProjectRule: false, projectRulePath: ''
```

Comment: there's a typo in parsingRulePAth

Comment: (typo was fixed by JRod)