# Jenkins Log Parser

Tags: jenkins, logging, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I was using https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/ plugin with freestyle Jenkins Jobs. But since moving to Jenkins Pipeline, I have not been able to integrate the log parser into the Declaratinve Pipeline syntax.

How can this be done? I also didn't find info in their docs. Also, what would be a good log parsing rule and where to specify it? In the Jenkinsfile also? Could you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't user log-parser, but a quick [glance at the issues](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/#issues) suggests it is not presently compatible;

[JENKINS-27208:  Make Log Parser Plugin compatible with Workflow](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27208)

[JENKINS-32866: Log Parser Plugin does not parse Pipeline console outputs](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32866)

**Update:**
This [old response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371659/598141) by Jesse Glick (Cloudbees; Jenkins sponsor) to similar question suggests it does in fact work now and suggests how to generate syntax, but OP complains [DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#plugin/log-parser) and [documentation is weak](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/log-parser/).

gdemengin wrote [pipeline-logparser](https://github.com/gdemengin/pipeline-logparser) to work around another issue [JENKINS-54304](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54304)

[Build Failure Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer/) may also be of use to you.
YMMV

Comment: Ufff, that's a shame. Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```
stage('check') {
  steps {
    echo 'checking logs from previous stages...'
    logParser failBuildOnError: true, parsingRulesPath: '/path/to/rules', useProjectRule: false, projectRulePath: ''
    }
}
```

The [pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) section in Jenkins allows you to get snippets for your Jenkinsfile